# Set Login User as database Onwer

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

What's the query to set a login user as db_owner during the creation of database.
Following is the set of queries, which I'm using right now,

```
Create database Test1;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::Test1 TO [DEVELOPMENT\d-testuser];
```

This servers my purpose, but here I have firstly created a database with default db_owner and then altered it. I need a query which will select [DEVELOPMENT\d-testuser] as my database owner during the creation of database itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the owner of model database as `[DEVELOPMENT\d-testuser]` and then any new databases that are created will automatically be owned by `[DEVELOPMENT\d-testuser]`.

I normally tend to set the database owner to `sa`. Our applications are not using (should never use) `sa` :-) so there is no harm in setting the db owner to `sa`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way of accomplishing this in one statement. You have to use alter authorization afterwards.

The two tricky ways I can think of are: 
You can set the Model database's owner to [DEVELOPMENT\d-testuser]. 
Or,
Log in with the login you want database owner to be.

> The owner is the user that creates the database. The database owner can be changed by using sp_changedbowner.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms176061.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: `sp_changedbowner` is announced deprecated. `Alter Authorization ..` is the way to go.

Comment: I was quoting msdn as is. Thanks for pointing out though..